# Word 2016 Text Vertically center in cell

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2016

[image]

As seen in the picture, why would text NOT vertically centered?

What's the problem?

OS: Windows 7 SP1 X64
Office 2016 Word X64
both in English

Comment: Did you press ` Enter ` after writing in the cell? if yes put the cursor after  ` y ` and press ` Delete '

Comment: Check the [paragraph formatting](http://www.howtogeek.com/school/microsoft-word-document-formatting-essentials/lesson2/all/): Spacing > After

Comment: @SuperSam I always check the invisible "enter". Thanks.

Comment: @ChenStatsYu Great. Answer added.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Why would text NOT be vertically centered?

It looks like the setting for Paragraph > Spacing > "Before" and "After" are different.

You appear to have `0` before and the default (some none `0` value) after.

Check this by going to "Paragraph" > "Indents and Spacing" tab > "Spacing":

> [image]

Make sure you have the same value for "Before" and "After".

Image Source [Lesson 2: Paragraph Formatting and Creating Lists](http://www.howtogeek.com/school/microsoft-word-document-formatting-essentials/lesson2/all/)